# AJAX to .NET posting of object with nested array

Tags: .net, ajax, post

I am trying to POST an object via jQuery AJAX call to .NET controller.

The object I am posting (ACDto) has among its properties a nested array (Keys) of objects

[image]

All is well but the nested array has its objects not bound/de-serialized correctly: all properties of the objects from the nested array are wither null, 0 or false.
Example:

View:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

I do `console.log()` the data before Ajax post and looks good (valid jSON)

What am I missing ?
I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you use List<ACBitdto> instead of IList<> ?

Comment: The solution proposed by Brian Mains worked.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using public properties instead of fields:

```
public class AcBitDto
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public boolon { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Fields will not work: [Binding public fields with ASP.NET MVC as well as public properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240611/binding-public-fields-with-asp-net-mvc-as-well-as-public-properties)

Comment: Thank you. The explanation has to do with the fact that DefaultModelBinder of .NET uses reflection and relies on the best practices, stating that object should not export publicly fields but properties.